# UITextViewDelegate method gives "Use of undeclared type URL" error in Swift 3 and Xcode 8.0

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

When i implement the `func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool` OR `func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool` method in my swift class, it gives error and warning as shown below.

error : `Use of undeclared type 'URL'`

warning : `Instance method 'textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:)' of protocol 'UITextViewDelegate'`

If I Change the class name to `NSURL` instead of `URL`, it compiles properly but warning never goes off.

Also the above methods are not called while interacting with URL in my textView

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the method header to something like this:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith url: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool
```

(The formal parameter `url` needs to be in lower case.)

This definitely is a bug of Swift/Xcode. The formal parameter `URL` is shadowing the type `URL`.

Comment: Yes, You are correct, the bug is in UITextViewDelegate methods. Thanks for your work around!